# Should I use KUbuntu or Ubuntu 16.04 for KDE Plasma desktop environment?

Tags: kubuntu, software-recommendation, kde, distro-recommendation

I am willing to use KDE Plasma 5 Desktop environment.

Should I use Kubuntu or Ubuntu 16.04?

If I would use Kubuntu, which advantages would it offer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubuntu is what you want.

Kubuntu is just Ubuntu, but without Unity and with KDE instead; that's why it's called Kubuntu. (KDE Ubuntu)

Ubuntu has nothing to do with KDE. You can install it, but you'll have to switch from Unity, and you'll run into theme issues.

I'm not sure where the confusion is honestly :p. I'm pretty sure Kubuntu says it uses KDE.

Comment: So that is the only difference between Kubuntu and Ubuntu 16?

Comment: Pretty much. Some packages are different, but just the ones that KDE needs and ones that KDE replaces from normal Ubuntu. If this answer helped, would you mind accepting it when you can? It'll be a little check mark below the arrows on the left.

Comment: Don't worry I will accept answer when system allows me. I am not newbie to Stack Exchange.